# how to get array input values into database using angularjs and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I have a form in which on click of button input fields get appended.
The form is as below.

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController" >
<form name="educdetailsform" novalidate>
   <label>Education Details</label></br>
    <button ng-click="addfield()">Add Education</button>
     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="text" name="qualification[]" data-ng-model="empData.qualification[]" placeholder="Qualification">
      <input type="text" name="year[]" data-ng-model="empData.year[]" placeholder="Year of Passing">
      <input type="text" name="percentage[]" data-ng-model="empData.percentage[]" placeholder="Percentage">
     </div> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" ng-click="saveUser()" />
  </form>
</body>
```

The angular JS code for appending input fields is as follows

```
 var module=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 module.controller('myController',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.items = [{}];

$scope.addfield = function(){
   $scope.items.push({});
}

 });
```

This is the code and functionality **http://jsfiddle.net/b0jtqzpj/2/**

How to get the fields to saveUser() function and then save the data into database table using PHP
Like, if the user has entered 3 entries i.e, the first entry must be saved in a row and 2nd entry in next row and 3rd entry in 3rd row. i.e, if 3 entries are entered in html form and submitted, 3 entries must be created in database table.

How do I catch data in angularjs saveUser() function and then save in database using PHP

Comment: are you familiar with ajax?

Comment: Yes, but this functionality must be done in angularjs. As the entire application is in angularjs

Comment: angularjs is a framework not a language. Notice the JS at the end which stands for JavaScript. Is there a reason why everything have to be written using angularjs? if so, check out this link. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ss5yo9xk/4/ for making ajax call and you need to use below code at php side to get post data :

```
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```